# Is it possible to connect an adsl splitter in this particular way?

Tags: adsl, splitter, adsl2+

As shown in the picture, Would it be alright if I attached the [adsl splitter](https://www.amazon.in/Link-DSL-Splitter-Telephone-Output/dp/B075D8R1LC) on an incoming line after the modem and before any other telephones? (leaving out the modem socket on the splitter)

Because as far as adsl splitters go, their job is to eliminate the high frequency noise used by ADSL services from being heard on the phones and what is shown in the picture below seems to be doing the job.

[image: phone line map]

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is also the splitter's job to eliminate low frequencies from the ADSL modem. They split the frequencies into the high and low part, hence the name splitter.

With this setup, your DSL connection might get out of sync, especially when you pick up the phone.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes.

The device you're using is a *[ADSL filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSL_filter?wprov=sfla1)* not a splitter. It filters out the frequencies used by the ADSL modem so that they are not disturbed (or heard) by voice calls made over the shared phone line.

You can connect any number of phone devices after the filter. They will work fine. In fact, some telcos install a filter directly in the demarc (customer access box where the line comes in from the telco) then run all the phone lines from it. This lets them provide a "dedicated" line to the customer for the ADSL service.